# Software to measure F-Score (formality) in English

Tags: computational-linguistics

Francis Heylighen and Jean-Marc Dewaele defined a measure of language formality called "F-Measure" in a paper published in 1999 titled "[Formality of Language: definition, measurement and behavioral determinants](http://pespmc1.vub.ac.be/Papers/Formality.pdf)".  Is there software available that examines English text and determines an F-score, or some other objective measure of formality?

Comment: Note that text is not language, and "formality" is defined quite differently in speech. Also, in order to count nouns as opposed to verbs (for instance), one needs a parse of each sentence, so start with a tagging parser.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this measure, but be aware that there's something else called an f-score that's used in information retrieval and machine learning, and which is widely implemented in software.  I.e. searching will give you a lot of false positives.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Maybe I should broaden the scope to software that provides more basic information like a histogram of parts-of-speech (e.g. nouns, verbs, pronouns, adjectives, adverbs, conjunctions, interjection, preposition).

Answer (score 1):

I work with Heylighen & Dewaele's F-score as part of my research. If you need code, please let me know. Here are the three papers I wrote on this topic (another in progress):

[paper 1](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~lahiri/cicling2011.pdf)
[paper 2](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.0069v2.pdf)
[paper 3](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02306.pdf)