# has there been any research conducted on formality and language learning?

Tags: written-language, spoken-language

I wanted to know if there has been any research regarding F-score or CF-score (Li, Haiying, "Comparing Two Measures for Formality." 2013.) affecting learning and/or language learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all take a look at this question might be helpful: [Software to measure F-Score (formality) in English](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6768/software-to-measure-f-score-formality-in-english)

Also you can read papers below to get a catch of the subject:

- Heylighen, F. and Dewaele, J.M., 1999. Formality of language: definition, measurement and behavioral determinants. Interner Bericht, Center “Leo Apostel”, Vrije Universiteit Brüssel.
- Upshur, J.A., 1968. Four Experiments On The Relation Between Foreign Language Teaching And Learning*. Language Learning, 18(1‐2), pp.111-124.